# redirect mydomain.com to openshift app without www

Tags: openshift

I am trying to deploy my app on Openshift.

I've added `www.mydomain.com`, and `mydomain.com` as aliases on Openshift and changed the cname record 'www' to `myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com`

when I try to access the app these are the results,

`myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com`  - Opens myapp

`www.mydomain.com` - redirects to myapp

`mydomain.com` - opens a blank page (the source of the blank page links to a godaddy's parking 
looks like this `http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

how can I make my `mydomain.com` point to the application at `myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com`

I have tried to change the 'A' record of the domain that pointed to `184.168.221.xx` but it needs to be an IP address not the app address.

thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've seen this Openshift Article or not https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way but it will walk you through step by step on how to acheive exactly what your asking.

The important part to pay attention to is:

> If you want to forward over your whole domain, such as mycompany.com
>   and not www.mycompany.com, then you either need to use Domain
>   Forwarding or find a DNS provider that allows "Naked" CName records.
>   Domain forwarding uses a web server to do a redirect.

Also be sure to check out https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/domain-with-no-www-dns-question-is-that-possible.

Comment: would you list some DNS providers that allows 'Naked' CName records?

Comment: As mentioned above by @joseph use CLoudFlare

Answer (score 0):

[CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com) allows you to create naked domains as `CNAME` records for free. Add CNAME records for both `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` which aliases `myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com`.