# GitHub pages repository linked to a custom domain, but the content is not rendering

Tags: rendering, github-pages, custom-domain

I've deployed my web site to GitHub pages and it worked perfectly with the GitHub URL. Then I configured my custom domain from Godaddy to my repository and I believe it's properly configured because when I go to my custom domain in the browser the title appears in the browser tab, however no content is being rendered on the screen. It's a blank page. Any guesses on what the problem could be is much appreciated. The domain name is "connorjaksik.com"

Answer (score 3):

Originally I didn't set up the DNS records properly on "GoDaddy".

I didn't add a CNAME with a value of my GitHub account username.

After that I noticed the domain was reaching my repository on github, but not rendering the content.

I had to change the repositories package.json "homepage" setting from the default, to my custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

The source HTML code for your blank page shows "`http://parked-content.godaddy.com/park/...`", which means the redirection is not happening and Godaddy provides a placeholder page in the meantime.

Check your DNS provider settings, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391915/6309): it needs to allow  "Naked" CName records in order to redirect your GitHub pages to a all domain name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The link you provided helped, however their was a string of problems that followed. Which I'll explain in the answer. Thanks